# Data binding not generating methods for some variables

Tags: android, android-databinding

i am implement data binding in my project but what strange behavior i can see, it is not generating methods for some variables i have defined in my xml. Even i have cleaned and rebuild my project many times. **But it is generating method for my model class.**

```
mBinding.setModel(mProfileViewModel);
```

which i created yesterday. i am really confused what is happening. Please help if you have any idea.

Below is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:chip="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <import
        name="view"
        type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="model"
        type="com.android.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="logoutCallBack"
        type="com.android.dialog.LogoutDialog.ILogoutListener"/>

    <variable
        name="logoutDialog"
        type="com.android.dialog.LogoutDialog"/>


    <variable
        name="activity"
        type="com.android.ui.profile.ProfileActivity" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/icl_action_bar"
        layout="@layout/actionbar_white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_logout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icl_action_bar"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_picture" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:letterSpacing="0.03"
                android:text="Herry"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="26sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:letterSpacing="0.03"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.14"
                android:text="Classrooms"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small">

                <com.plumillonforge.android.chipview.ChipView
                    android:id="@+id/chipview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    chip:chip_padding="5dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/width_divider_subject_activity"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:onClick="@{() -> logoutDialog.showDialog(activity,logoutCallBack)}"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
        android:text="@string/lbl_logout"
        android:textColor="@color/colorOnBoardingPageIndicator"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my Activity

```
public class ProfileActivity extends BaseActivity implements LogoutDialog.ILogoutListener {

private ActivityProfileBinding mBinding;
private ProfileViewModel mProfileViewModel;


@Override
protected void onCreatingBase(Bundle savedInstanceState, Intent intent) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_profile);
    mProfileViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ProfileViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(ProfileViewModel.class);

    mProfileViewModel.getLogoutResponse().observe(this, mLogoutObserver);
    mBinding.setModel(mProfileViewModel);
    registerObservers(mProfileViewModel);
    mProfileViewModel.fetchClassRooms();
}


/**
 * Observer listening to the response of Logout API
 */
private Observer<ApiResponse> mLogoutObserver = new Observer<ApiResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ApiResponse classRoomResponses) {

    }
};


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
}

@Override
public void onYesClicked() {
    mProfileViewModel.doLogout();
}
}
```

LogoutDialog class

```
public class LogoutDialog {

public static void showDialog(Context context,final ILogoutListener logoutListner ){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.logout_desc))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.yes_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    logoutListner.onYesClicked();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.no_text), null)
            .show();

}

public interface ILogoutListener {
    void onYesClicked();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried invalidating cache and restarted the android studio?

Comment: Yes. after invalidating cache and restart it working fine. Thanks @Ganesh

Comment: Happy to help :)